# How does firebase detect that a user is already signed in on android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This question is out of curiosity only. In a regular android application that requires sign-in or sign-up, I would use `SharedPreference` in android to save the token of the user and this way everytime the user opens the app I would check the token in order to figure out if he's already signed in or not.

However, using Firebase it seems that it only requires the following code:

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    //Already logged in
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My question is, how does this happen? How does `firebaseAuth` return the logged in user?

Comment: Didn't you pass the token to Firebase? If not, are you sure you've set the security rules in Firebase properly?

Comment: They use local storage, not sure if SharedPreferences exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase SDK manages the token that identifies the user, and automatically refreshes it when it expires.  It works in conjunction with Play services in order to make sure your app and only your app has access to the user's information.

The implementation details of this are private, but you can be certain there is some form of secure local persistence for this data.